# Does moving funds from one account to another locally require a transaction fee?

Tags: json-rpc

I am developing a simple wallet with PHP. Right now I don't have the ability to "move" any funds around to test with. I am wondering does the "move" command require a transaction fee?

Comment: are you asking about bitcoin? bitcoin does not have accounts and move command.

Comment: Spending outputs requires a fee to be paid to miners. For testing purposes, you should connect to the bitcoin testnet (avoid main-net tx fees, and losses due to wallet bugs).

Answer (score 1):

Answering to the subject of this question:

> Does moving funds from one account to another locally require a transaction fee?

Yes!

If you move(transfer) funds from one wallet to another wallet, there will be a transaction fee for sure.

But,

If you are doing this simply in your server, that is within the website and internal database, then no, there is no transaction fees.

A transaction fee will be levied only if you transfer from one wallet to another in blockchain, not internal to your own database.